# Debugging ingestion failure in Kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I see a bunch of 'permanent' failures when I fire the following command:-

```
.show ingestion failures | where FailureKind == "Permanent"
```

For all the entries that are returned the error code is `UpdatePolicy_UnknownError`.

The `Details` column for all the entries shows something like this:-

```
Failed to invoke update policy. Target Table = 'mytable', Query = '<some query here>': The remote server returned an error: (409) Conflict.: : :
```

What does this error mean? How do I find out the root cause behind these failures? The information I find through this command is not sufficient. I also copied `OperationId` for a sample entry and looked it up against the operations info:-

```
.show operations | where OperationId == '<sample operation id>'
```

But all I found in the `Status` is the message `Failed performing non-transactional update policy.` I know it failed, but can we find out the underlying reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"(409) Conflict" error usually comes from writing to the Azure storage.
In general, this error should be treated as a transient one. 
If it happens in the writing of the main part of the ingestion, it should be retried (****).
In your case, it happens in writing the data of the **non-transactional** update policy - this write is not retried - the data enters the main table, but not the dependent table.
In the case of a transactional update policy, the whole ingestion will be failed and then retried.

(****) There was a bug in treating such an error, it was treated as permanent for a short period for the main ingestion data. The bug should be fixed now.

Comment: thanks, but not sure if the bug is fixed because otherwise why am I seeing this now? Looking at the 'FailedOn' in the result , I can tell this it's happening everyday, though number of errors vary from day to day. And as you can see from my queries, I am filtering only permanent errors. So these are not transient errors.

Comment: I see stars in the answer, looks like some link was not properly pasted.

Comment: The stars were used to postpone the explanation. After looking at your cluster, I can say that the bug I mentioned is not relevant in your case. There are several reasons for the failures. All the failures of non-transactional update policy are considered as permanent as they won't be retries (as the opposite of transactional policy where no data is ingested to the main table and the whole ingestion can be retried).